# How do I add UIImageView to UIAlertView in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiimage, uialertview

```
UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView () { 
    Title = alertTitle, Message = alertMessage
};

UIImageView imageview = new UIImageView ();
UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile ("Resources/Default.png");
imageview.Image = img;
alert.AddSubview (imageview);

alert.AddButton (alertPositiveBtnText);
alert.AddButton (alertNegativeBtnText);
alert.Show ();
```

This is the piece of code i am working upon.I want to show an image as background in alertbox.I have set the`UIImageView` and`UIAlertView` but image is not showing up.Help me?

Answer (score 2):

Guilherme Torres Castro is correct. versions 7 and later do not support adding UIImageView as subView. 
However, for version 7 and above you can use this:

```
 UIAlertView Msg = new UIAlertView()
                    {
                        Title = "Title",
                        Message = "Content" 
                    };
                    UIImageView uiIV = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("ImgFile.Png"));
                    Msg.SetValueForKey(uiIV, (NSString)"accessoryView");
                    Msg.AddButton("OK");
                    Msg.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far i Know on IOS 7 and up it´s impossible to add custom view in UIAlertView. You have to use a custom component to mimic the Alert, there a few options for Android.

I found [this library for Xamarin](https://github.com/jsauve/SIAlertView.Xamarin), but didn't test it.

Answer (score -2):

```
UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create("Title", "Message Content" , UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
UIImageView imageview = new UIImageView();
alert.Add(imageview);
```

Comment: Code-only answers provide little value to other readers. It's strongly advised that you provide some explanation as to what you did to reach your conclusion.

Comment: Somebody flagged your answer. I edited it [as part of the reviewing system](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18743558) as it's still an attempt to answer the question. You should add some explanations to prevent others from [(incorrectly) flagging your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358727/1364007).